# Elixir Date.diff/2 is undefined or private

Tags: elixir

I am new to Elixir and trying to run some scripts from elixir documentation, testing Date structure gave a strange result because
    `Date.compare(~D[2016-04-16], ~D[2016-04-28])` is returning :lt
while when trying to run `Date.diff(~D[2016-04-16], ~D[2016-04-28])` I am getting this error

```
(UndefinedFunctionError) function Date.diff/2 is undefined or private
(elixir) Date.diff(~D[2016-04-16], ~D[2016-04-28])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.diff/2` was added in Elixir 1.5 (as you can see [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/releases/tag/v1.5.0)). I am pretty sure you are using previous version. By running `elixir -v` you can check what version you have currently installed.

Answer (score 0):

`Date.compare` is functioning correctly here. `:lt` isn't an error code but rather a symbol indicating the result of a comparison.

Any comparison between two dates will yield one of the following three symbols:

- `:lt` - "Less Than"
- `:gt` - "Greater Than"
- `:eq` - "Equal"

If you need to get the difference in dates as a number of days (i.e `Date.diff`), you will need to upgrade to an Elixir version > 1.4.5.